# Where did my quest NPC go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I decided to take A Scroll for Anska sometime last week, and I had Anska following me everywhere. I figured out that I was way too underleveled for the quest, so I went around to various locations to do quests and level up. I noticed she followed me occasionally when I would fast travel to places.

I'm back at the cave where I need to do her quest, but I'm not seeing her anywhere. Does she just...magically appear and disappear sometimes?

I'm hoping she didn't die when I went back to Whiterun and a dragon spawned in there, too...

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I went further into the High Gate Ruins and she mysteriously appeared.